# does google map event triggers the google map to be reloaded?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I've recently created a website that display uses a Google map. I was wondering does the `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')` causes the map to be reloaded from Google? Or is it just plain UI redraw from local machine that doesn't call back to Google api?

Answer (score 1):

from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map):

> resize - None - Developers should trigger this event on the map when the div changes size: google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize').

This event informs the API that the map DIV has changed size, it will do what is needed, which may involve fetching additional tiles from the tile servers, but not necessarily (if the map got smaller, there shouldn't be any additional tiles required).  It won't cause an additional load of the API.